# Find the biggest fraction - struct question

Tags: c

I'm a computer science student and I did a test recently when I solved a cool question in a weird way but I think I succeeded.
I'm ask before I appeal the test.

The question is to find the largest fraction from an array of struct.

The way I solved the question is by dividing into cases instead of a common denominator.

*** The Denominator always smaller then the numerator and the number is positive

*** After I run few end cases I did it wrong.

Thanks for all !

```
Fraction who_is_the_biggest(Fraction* a, int size) {
    Fraction max = a[0];
    int i;
    // find the max num
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i].whole > max.whole) {
            max = a[i];
        }
        // if a[i] == max do compare bewteen numerator and denominator
        if (a[i].whole == max.whole) {
            if (a[i].denominator == max.denominator && a[i].numerator > max.numerator) { // 3/4 & 2/4 --- > 3/4
                max = a[i];
            }
            else if (a[i].numerator == max.numerator && a[i].denominator < max.denominator) { // 3/5 & 3/6 --- > 3/5
                max = a[i];

            }
            else if (a[i].numerator != max.numerator && a[i].denominator != max.denominator) { // 2/100 & 3/4 --> 3/4 
                if (a[i].numerator > max.numerator && a[i].denominator < max.denominator) {
                    max = a[i];
                }

            }

        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: What is the `num` field of `Fraction`?

Comment: You might want to clarify "find the largest fraction from an array of struct". It looks like you are asking whether your code is correct; but how can anyone judge that without knowing what the code should do? Maybe "find the largest fraction from an array of struct" sounds perfectly clear to you, but not to me. Not sure about others.

Comment: the num is the the number like 1 2/3 num = 1 (5/3)

Comment: Your question is asking for the largest *fraction*, so why are you even considering the `num` (whole number) part? Further, shouldn't the returned structure have that `num` member set to zero?

Comment: You can't reliably make this check without performing the actual division, or multiplication in order to bring the fractions to the common denominator. Your comparisons are not covering all of the cases.

Comment: Here is a demonstration - https://ideone.com/D4JGt4, as you can see it is returning `5/6` between `5/6` and `6/7`.

Comment: @anatolygn OP wants to see what fraction is the biggest from an array of fractions, like how 1/2 is bigger then 2/6

Comment: Your first three cases are okay, I think (as long as all the fractions are guaranteed to be normalized).  It's the last case where things break down.  If both the numerator and denominator are unequal, I don't think there's any quick-and-dirty heuristic.  In that case, at least, I don't think you have any choice but to do the equivalent of the complete division, or the common denominator thing.

Comment: @SteveSummit Did not have enough patience to properly test my solution form the answer but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You algorithm is completely wrong.

```
Test it 
int main(void)
{
    Fraction a[] = 
    {
        {.whole = 0, .numerator = 98, 101}, {.whole = 0, .numerator = 97, 99}
    };

    Fraction f = who_is_the_biggest(a, 2);
    printf("%d %d %f\n", f.numerator, f.denominator, ((double)a[0].numerator / a[0].denominator) / ((double)a[1].numerator / a[1].denominator));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xPbWPzTWd

It returns `a[0]` but `a[0]` is smaller than `a[1]`.

You need to find the smallest common denominator, then compare the fraction parts.

> I did a test recently when I solved a cool question in a weird way
> but I think I succeeded

No, you did not succeed, do not appeal.

It should work (but I would not show it to your teacher). Asuumptions: numerator <= denomitator if `whole` is not zero. Otherwise you need to normalize the fraction:

```
#define SWAPFRAC(f) do{unsigned t = (f).denominator; (f).denominator = (f).numerator; (f).numerator = t;}while(0)

int compareFrac(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(f1.whole == f2.whole)
        {
            if(f1.denominator == f2.denominator && (f1.numerator == f2.numerator))
            {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }
            SWAPFRAC(f1);
            SWAPFRAC(f2);

            f2.whole = f2.numerator / f2.denominator;
            f2.numerator %= f2.denominator;
            f1.whole = f1.numerator / f1.denominator;
            f1.numerator %= f1.denominator;
        }
        else 
        {
            result = f1.whole > f2.whole;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```